# while loop in C programing

Tags: c, while-loop

Write a program that contains the loop

```
while (scanf("%1f", &salary) == 1) {...}
```

within the body of the loop compute a 17% federal withholding tax and a 3% state withholding tax and print these values along with the corresponding salary. Accumulate the sums of all salaries and taxes printed. Print these sums after the program exits the while loop.

My current code:

```
float salary, federal_tax, state_tax, salary_after_tax, salary_sum, tax_sum, salary_after_tax_sum;
printf("Enter Salary: $");
while (scanf("%lf", &salary) == 1)
{
salary_sum = salary;
federal_tax = salary*(.17);
state_tax = salary*(.03);
tax_sum = federal_tax + state_tax;
salary_after_tax = salary - federal_tax - state_tax;
salary_after_tax_sum = salary_after_tax;
printf("Salary before tax = %lf", salary);
printf("Federal tax = %lf", federal_tax);
printf("State tax = %lf", state_tax);
printf("Salary after tax = %lf\n", salary_after_tax);
break;
}
printf("total salary before tax = %lf", salary_sum);
printf("total tax = %lf", tax_sum);
printf("total salary after tax = %lf\n", salary_after_tax_sum);
system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

For some reason it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Homework questions _are_ acceptable, but please tag them as such!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a little sparse. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think breaking out of the loop after the first iteration defeats the purpose of having a loop.  Perhaps you should remove the break and actually collect multiple values from the user to sum.

Comment: @AlexMartelli the homework tag is deprecated..

Answer (score 3):

Your `scanf` specifier is `%lf` (your problem statement says `%1f` instead, is that intentional?) and yet you're storing into a `float`. My `scanf(3)` says `%lf` specifies a `double`.

Incidentally, `float` has much less precision than many programmers may expect, just about seven digits, so using `double` instead is probably a good idea for salaries.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your `..._sum` variable to 0 outside the loop, and increment them with `+=` in the loop; what you're doing now instead is reassigning them every time through the loop, and that isn't *summing*!-)

Comment: doesn't work, I mean doesn't give me any valid outputs!!! sry.

Thanks Alex, I added 
salary_sum = 0;
num = 0;

While .....

salary_sum = salary;
salary_sum+=salary;
num++;

but it still gives me zero for everything. sry I am just starting!

Answer (score 0):

You lied to the compiler and it got its revenge: the `%lf` format needs to go with a pointer-to-double, while you provide only a pointer-to-float. This means **undefined behavior** in C lingo (anything may happen).

Fix your float declarations by turning them into doubles.